# Find files with content matching regex

Tags: python, file-system, memory-optimization

Today I wanted to find a program that I wrote a while ago. I knew that it contained a certain regex, but I couldn't for the life of me remember the file name I saved it under. I knew I could use Windows search, but it takes more time then it would for me to write a Python program to do the same.

The main two things I use are `os.walk` and `re`, the former to traverse the entire directory tree, where the latter is to match the data. I also use `codecs` to allow me to read files with special characters. And finally I use `argparse` to get the input from the end user.

Some files still error when using `codecs` such as pngs or other raw data files, so I skip these.

I kept the arguments simple, you pass a regex and a path. You can also pass any of the regex flags. So the following will search for 'metaclass' in any case, in the files below '`D:\data`'.

```
python search.py "metaclass" "D:\data" -i
```

The code is fairly small and mostly just adds information to the parser. It also runs in both Python2 and Python3.

```
import re
import codecs
import argparse
import operator
from os import walk
from os.path import join
# Add reduce to global scope for Python3
try:
    from functools import reduce
except ImportError:
    pass

# Descriptions are the same as Python's re descriptions
# https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#module-contents
# https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#module-contents
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Search file contense.')
parser.add_argument('regex', help='regex to search for')
parser.add_argument('path', help='path to root of recursive search')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--ascii', action="store_true",
                    help='(Python3 only) Make `\w`, `\W`, `\b`, `\B`, `\d`, '
                         '`\D`, `\s` and `\S` perform ASCII-only matching '
                         'instead of full Unicode matching. This is only '
                         'meaningful for Unicode patterns, and is ignored for '
                         'byte patterns.')
parser.add_argument('-i', '--ignorecase', action="store_true",
                    help='Perform case-insensitive matching; expressions like '
                         '`[A-Z]` will match lowercase letters, too. This is '
                         'not affected by the current locale.')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--locale', action="store_true",
                    help='Make `\w`, `\W`, `\b`, `\B`, `\s` and `\S` '
                         'dependent on the current locale.')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--multiline', action="store_true",
                    help='When specified, the pattern character \'^\' matches '
                         'at the beginning of the string and at the beginning '
                         'of each line (immediately following each newline); '
                         'and the pattern character \'$\' matches at the end '
                         'of the string and at the end of each line '
                         '(immediately preceding each newline). By default, '
                         '\'^\' matches only at the beginning of the string, '
                         'and \'$\' only at the end of the string and '
                         'immediately before the newline (if any) at the end '
                         'of the string.')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--dotall', action="store_true",
                    help='Make the \'.\' special character match any '
                         'character at all, including a newline; without this '
                         'flag, \'.\' will match anything except a newline.')
parser.add_argument('-u', '--unicode', action="store_true",
                    help='Make `\w`, `\W`, `\b`, `\B`, `\d`, `\D`, `\s` and '
                         '`\S` dependent on the Unicode character properties '
                         'database.')
parser.add_argument('-x', '--verbose', action="store_true",
                    help='This flag allows you to write regular expressions '
                         'that look nicer and are more readable by allowing '
                         'you to visually separate logical sections of the '
                         'pattern and add comments. Whitespace within the '
                         'pattern is ignored, except when in a character '
                         'class or when preceded by an unescaped backslash. '
                         'When a line contains a # that is not in a character '
                         'class and is not preceded by an unescaped '
                         'backslash, all characters from the leftmost such # '
                         'through the end of the line are ignored.')
parser.add_argument('--debug', action="store_true",
                    help='Display debug information about compiled expression.')


def get_args():
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    path = args.pop('path')
    regex = args.pop('regex')
    regex_flags = [getattr(re, k.upper()) for k, v in args.items() if v]
    regex = re.compile(regex, reduce(operator.or_, regex_flags, 0))
    return path, regex


def get_files(path, regex):
    search = regex.search
    for root, dirs, files in walk(path):
        for name in files:
            with codecs.open(join(root, name), 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
                try:
                    data = f.read()
                except (UnicodeError, ValueError):
                    continue
            match = search(data)
            if match is not None:
                yield join(root, name), match


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for path, match in get_files(*get_args()):
        print('match: {!r} ({})'.format(path, match.group()))
```

My main concerns are:

- How/where I write the parser.
- How much my functions do. Do they violate SRP?
- Is there a more memory efficient way to `search`? Reading the entire file seems bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `try` block for importing `reduce` is unnecessary.  In Python 2, it is still in the `functools` module, but it is *also* in the `__builtin__` module.

---

You have a typo in your description.  It should be 'contents', not 'contense'.

---

Since `ASCII` is a Python3-only flag, you might want to account for that in `get_args()`.  It really isn't very complicated.  Just add:

```
if args['ascii']:
    try:
        re.ASCII
    except AttributeError:
        parser.error("--ascii is compatible with Python 3 only")
```

---

I think `get_args()` is fine in how much it does.  A regex of `th(kl` is invalid.  Invalid arguments should be caught in the function that gets the arguments.  I would, however, add a function that determines if a given regex is found in a file.  That way `get_files()` could look like this:

```
def get_files(path, regex):
    return (name
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)
            for name in files
                if file_matches(file, regex)
    )
```

---

From [How do I re.search or re.match on a whole file without reading it all into memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/454589/5827958), you can use [`mmap.mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap) to save on memory usage.  Note that Python 3 requires a bytes regex when using that function.